# Get index value of an item with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get an index value of an element with a given class. For example, I have.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li class="open">Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
var index = $('li .open').index();
console.log(index);
```

**What I expect:**

Console result expected should equal **2**. What I get is **-1**.

Anyways, I am obviously doing something wrong so any help with this would be much appreciated. I started a fiddle here: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/gENcn/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space makes a difference:

- `li .open` selects an element with a class of `open` that's inside of an `<li>` element.
- `li.open` selects an `<li>` element with a class of `open`.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gENcn/2/**

Comment: Well that was a rookie mistake. Thanks for the help, I will accept when SO allows me to.